# MongoDB: Point not in interval when using $near operator with $maxDistance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geojson

When I try to find all members within 50km of Salt Lake City, Utah from the Mongo shell I get the error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "point not in interval of [ -180, 180 ] :: caused by :: { 0: 0.0, 1: 50000.0 }",
    "code" : 16433
}
```

Here is the query I am running:

```
db.members.find(
   { 'geo.point' :
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry : {
               type : "Point" ,
               coordinates : [ 111.000 , 40.000 ]
            },
            $maxDistance : 50000
          }
       }
    }
)
```

Member schema is like this:

```
var memberSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        first: {type:String, default:''},
        last: {type:String, default:''},
    },
    geo: {
        latitude: {type:String, default:''},
        longitude: {type:String, default:''},
        country: {type:String, default:''},
        state: {type:String, default:''},
        place: {type:String, default:''},
        zip: {type:String, default:''},
        point: {type: [Number], index: '2d'}
    }
});
```

Member object in DB looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
    "name": {
        "first": "Thom",
        "last": "Allen"
    },
    "geo" : {
        "point" : [ -111.8833, 40.7500 ],
        "zip" : "84115",
        "state" : "UT",
        "country" : "US",
        "longitude" : "-111.8833",
        "latitude" : "40.7500"
    }
}
```

Is it possible that my fields are not stored in the correct format? If I change 50000 to anything below 180 it will work, but that is not how it should function according to the docs here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

** Just a heads up, the proper mongo location array IS in fact [longitude, latitude].

Comment: can you share information on document schema, version of the database and type of index created?

Comment: v2.4.9, I did include info about the relevant part field in the schema. Do you need to see more @JohnPetrone?

Comment: We probably need to see your schema but it looks as if you have legacy co-ordinate pairs and not a [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) formatted object. You can also only use a "2d" index with legacy pairs and "2dspere" indexes will not work.

Comment: Agree with @NeilLunn - we do need to see your schema to nail this down.

Comment: Okay I updated the schema in the original post @NeilLunn

Comment: @JohnPetrone you may want to take a look as well. Thank you both!

Comment: can you add the type of index that you have created on the collection? like the output from db.member.getIndexes()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. First, I think your query is off - you are querying for coordinates : `[ 111.000 , 40.000 ]` and it should be coordinates : `[ -111.000 , 40.000 ]`

Second, the example data point your provide `[ -111.8833, 40.7500 ]` is more than 50 km from your corrected query point, it's actually about 122 km (test it here: http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/ )

So, correcting for those two issues if I store the data in mongodb as you have stored it I can do the following:

1) create the correct index:

`db.members.ensureIndex({ "geo.point": "2dsphere" })`

2) run this query:

`db.members.find({ 'geo.point':
                   {$geoWithin:
                     {$centerSphere: [[ -111.000 , 40.000 ], 113/6371]}
                   }
                  } )`

Note that I've divided 113 km/ 6371 which gives you radians which is what is required for this specific query.

Try it yourself. In general you will be better off if you can store things in the future using GeoJSON but with your existing schema and the above index and query I'm able to get the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in your data is the format for legacy co-ordinate pairs but you are trying to query using the GeoJSON syntax.

The only valid index form for legacy co-ordinate pairs is a "2d" index, so if you have created a "2d sphere" index that will not work. So you need to remove any "2d sphere" index and create a "2d" index as follows:

```js
db.members.ensureIndex({ "geo.point": "2d" })
```

If you actually intend to use the GeoJSON form and "2dsphere" index type, then you need the data to support it, for example:

```js
 { 
     "loc" : { 
         "type" : "Point",
         "coordinates" : [ 3, 6 ]
     } 
 }
```

So it needs that underlying structure of "type" and "coordinates" in order to use this index type and query form.